# Uninstalling Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, uninstallation

I uninstalled Homebrew on my MAC, but got this message at the end:

The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:

- `/opt/homebrew/SECURITY.md`
- `/opt/homebrew/etc/`
- `/opt/homebrew/share/`
- `/opt/homebrew/var/`

You may wish to remove them yourself.

I was able to remove the first item, but when I tried to remove the remaining three with "rmdir," I kept getting the "_____ is a directory" output. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `rmdir` only works if the directory is empty, looking at [this linux man page](https://ss64.com/bash/rmdir.html). You could try to remove them using `rm -rf <path to folder>` instead.

Comment: I see. Thank you. All the Homebrew files and directories are isolated, correct? Is there little to no risk of messing up my computer's other files and directories?

Comment: Yes, you should be fine if you delete only the ones that you listed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an answer, but seems these folder are left on purpose. They are not part of the Homebrew package manager itself. But config, file, cache, etc content generated by brew-installed package.

Especially, make sure you have a backup of these settings before you remove it with `rm -rf`.